# Error in Jumping to method after some delay time

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I m developing a quiz based app and in this m trying to jump on some method after some delay time but unfortunately m getting some Run time Error..
Here's that code..

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
                @Override
                public void run() 
                {
                    resetcolor();
                    nextpage();
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    showdata();
                }
            }, 6000);
```

And here's my Log cat Error..

```
09-12 12:11:06.775: W/dalvikvm(489): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChild(ViewRoot.java:607)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.view.ViewRoot.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRoot.java:633)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:2505)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:5115)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.widget.TextView.invalidateDrawable(TextView.java:3796)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.invalidateSelf(Drawable.java:300)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.selectDrawable(DrawableContainer.java:227)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:97)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.setState(Drawable.java:400)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.drawableStateChanged(CompoundButton.java:271)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.view.View.refreshDrawableState(View.java:7248)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:115)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedStateForView(RadioGroup.java:179)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.widget.RadioGroup.check(RadioGroup.java:159)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck(RadioGroup.java:205)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at com.example.quizapp.Firstques$1$1.run(Firstques.java:234)
09-12 12:11:06.789: E/AndroidRuntime(489):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:289)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite your code as follows:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(6000);
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          resetcolor();
          nextpage();
          rg.clearCheck();
          showdata();
        }
      });
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
  }
}).start();
```

Your problem is that you cannot touch UI elements from background thread. The code above executes the UI changes in the main thread (also known as "UI thread").

Answer (score 1):

TimerTask runs on a different thread. Ui should be updated or accessed on ui thread. So use `runOnUiThread`

Inside the timertask run method

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       resetcolor();
                       nextpage();
                       rg.clearCheck();
                       showdata();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 6000);
```

Or use a Handler

```
Handler m_handler;
Runnable m_handlerTask ;
handler= new Handler()
m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
{
    @Override 
    public void run() { 

         // do something
          resetcolor();
          nextpage();
          rg.clearCheck();
          showdata() 

         m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 6000);    

    }
};
m_handlerTask.run();
```

To stop the handler`m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask)`

Comment: @shiv did you see the edited answer and don't highlight your comments with bold.