# Does TimerTask executing in new thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timertask

Can I consider that code in `run` will be executed in new Thread or I must use `AsyncTask`?

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(); // Создаем таймер
        final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() { // Определяем задачу
            @Override
            public void run() {
                uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                    }
                });
            }

            ;
        }, 0L, 10L * 1000); // интервал - 10000 миллисекунд, 0 миллисекунд до первого запуска.
```

**UPDATED**

I got an error in this code:

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        final Handler uiHandler = new Handler();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (songRefreshing) {
                    uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                                HttpResponse response = null;
                                response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(Const.php_url));
                                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                                    out.close();
                                    String responseString = out.toString();
                                    if (app.getCurSong() == null || app.getCurSong().intern() != responseString.intern()) {
                                        app.setCurSong(responseString);
                                        song_name.setText(app.getCurSong());
                                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "refreshCurSung - " + responseString);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

            ;
        }, 0L, 10L * 1000); // 10s interval
```

Error:

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1178)
    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:394)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:245)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:220)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:590)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:510)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:488)
```

Does it mean that TimerTask don't executing in new thread?

Comment: what are you trying to do? why do you use a timer if you are going to post to a handler anyway? (also, which run are you talking about?)

Comment: you can use handler instead of a timer

Comment: I need to do one action every 10s. Thatis why I use Timer.

Comment: @p.Valery why can't you use a handler? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757492/error-in-jumping-to-method-after-some-delay-time/18757573#18757573

Comment: I don't have experience with this type of code using handler..

Comment: thread inside a thread??

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question directly, a quote taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html):

**Class Overview**

> Timers schedule one-shot or recurring tasks for execution. Prefer
>   ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor for new code.
>
> Each timer has one thread on which tasks are executed sequentially.
>   When this thread is busy running a task, runnable tasks may be subject
>   to delays.
>
> One-shot are scheduled to run at an absolute time or after a relative
>   delay.
>
> Recurring tasks are scheduled with either a fixed period or a fixed
>   rate:
>
> With the default fixed-period execution, each successive run of a task
>   is scheduled relative to the start time of the previous run, so two
>   runs are never fired closer together in time than the specified
>   period. With fixed-rate execution, the start time of each successive
>   run of a task is scheduled without regard for when the previous run
>   took place. This may result in a series of bunched-up runs (one
>   launched immediately after another) if delays prevent the timer from
>   starting tasks on time. When a timer is no longer needed, users should
>   call cancel(), which releases the **timer's thread** and other resources.
>   Timers not explicitly cancelled may hold resources indefinitely.
>
> This class does not offer guarantees about the real-time nature of
>   task scheduling. Multiple threads can share a single timer without
>   synchronization.

So yeah, it's a Thread.

**UPDATE** (following the update of the Question):

The current implementation could contain a lot of flaws, that's why I would recommend you to put the code from the `Runnable` in an `AsyncTask` (and put the whole bunch of code in the `doInBackground` method). There you can easily control it.

Furthermore, I think that `@Overriding` the `run()` two times one inside of another could lead you to a deadlock or something. Since the `TimerTask` is in fact a Thread, then I don't think you need a separate `Runnable` inside of it.

Remove the implementation of the `Runnable` for a start and try to launch the `TimerTask` with the `HttpClient` inside of it (without the `Runnable`). If you can't manage to do it, then put the code (as suggested) in an `AsyncTask` (you'll have a prettier implementation like this anyway).

Thx

Comment: Look updete part of post please. May be you are wrong or I did something wrong.